# static const vs. const static

Tags: c++, class, constants

I do not understand the difference between these two statements in my C++ class:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
  private:
     static const int var = 0;            // Option 1
     const static int var = 0;            // Option 2
};
```

What is the difference b/w Option 1 and Option 2?? They both compile.

Comment: Maybe reading [this link](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) might help you understand declarations better.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I, among others, don't quite trust the *spiral rule*. An in this particular case it will not help at all as *spiral* or not the sequence differs only in the order of `const` and `static`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I agree.  About the only time the spiral rule works is when the declarations are so simple that you don't need it anyway.  Otherwise, it's misleading at best, and completely wrong at worst.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

They mean exactly the same thing. You're free to choose whichever you think is easier to read.

In C, you *should* place `static` at the start, but it's not yet required. I'm not sure if C++ followed C in this regard.

> 6.11.5 Storage-class specifiers
>
> 1 The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration
>   specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature.

Answer (score 50):

`static`, `const` (here, anyway) and the type (e.g. `int`) are all part
of the declaration specifier.  *Historically*, the declaration specifier
was an unordered list of keywords and type names, so:

```
static unsigned int const var;
static unsigned const int var;
static int unsigned const var;
static int const unsigned var;
static const unsigned int var;
static const int unsigned var;
unsigned static int const var;
unsigned static const int var;
unsigned int static const var;
unsigned int const static var;
unsigned const static int var;
unsigned const int static var;
int static unsigned const var;
int static const unsigned var;
int unsigned static const var;
int unsigned const static var;
int const static unsigned var;
int const unsigned static var;
const static unsigned int var;
const static int unsigned var;
const unsigned static int var;
const unsigned int static var;
const int static unsigned var;
const int unsigned static var;
```

were all legal, and all meant the same thing.

I think that this is still the case, both in C and in C++, but if I'm
not mistaken, C has deprecated putting the storage class specifier
(`static`) any where but at the beginning.  This is at any rate an
almost universal convention, so you should normally put the `static`
(and `extern`, etc.) at the start.

Note too that being unordered only applies to the declaration specifier.
Within the declarators which follow, the cv-qualifier(s) *must* follow
what they qualify; for reasons of orthogonality, you should normally
always put the cv-qualifiers after what they modify (i.e. `int const`,
and not `const int`).

Finally, it seems to be a widespread convention to present the type
modifiers before the type, with the signedness modifier (`signed` or
`unsigned`) preceding the length modifier (`short`, `long` or `long
long`).  It's also fairly frequent to drop the `int` if a modifier is
present, so people write `unsigned`, rather than `unsigned int`, and
`long`, rather than `long int`.  This is far from universal, however.

Given this, the first way the declaration is written, above, is
preferred, although it is quite acceptable to drop the `int`.

Comment: BTW, did you mean *either* as opposed to neither?

Comment: @user1054424 I missed the `int` in the original declaration.  Without at least one type name, the declaration would be illegal.  But with the `int`, it should be "either" or "both", and not "neither".

Comment: I think the convention is to drop the `int` if there is a length modifier, but not if there is only a signedness modifier. I.e., almost all code I see uses `unsigned int` instead of `unsigned`.

Comment: I'll end up using both `unsigned int` & `unsigned` depending on the context. If I'm declaring a member variable I'll use `unsigned int`, if I'm declaring it as a counter for array or vector indexing within loops then I'll typically use `unsigned`. As for `static` I typically use that first before anything. The only thing that I disagree with from the above is I don't like the `const` after; its a personal preference. When I read and see my code `static const unsigned int`  I know that it has static storage, it is  `constant` & an `unsigned int`. The other way it reads backwards to me.

Answer (score 8):

They are the same. But I would always go for Option 1 for a simple reason that the keywords `const` and `int` fit better when juxtaposed as they define the datatype. Where as the keyword `static` defines the accessibility of that variable.

Answer (score 3):

They are the same.
See this discussion: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/140177-const-static-vs-static-const