# What's the difference between declaration 'static const' and 'const static'

Tags: c++

When I do declaration in C++ ,

```
static const int SECS = 60 * MINUTE;
const static int SECS = 60 * MINUTE;
```

is there any difference between these two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`const` always applies to the type to its immediate left; if there is none, it applies to the next type on its right.

So the following three declarations

```
const static int SECS = 60 * MINUTE;
// or
static const int SECS = 60 * MINUTE;
// or
static int const SECS = 60 * MINUTE;
```

are all equal. `static` applies to the whole declaration; and const applies to the `int` type.

The position of `const` would only make a difference if you had a "more complicated" type, like e.g. a reference or a pointer:

```
int a;
const int * b = a; // 1.
int * const c = a; // 2.
```

In this case there is a difference between the place of `const` - for 1. it applies to the int (i.e. it is a pointer to a const int, i.e. you can't change the value), and for 2., it applies to the pointer (i.e. you can't modify where c points to).

Answer (score 9):

> is there any difference between these two?

No. Not at all. The order doesn't matter (in this case!).

Moreover, if you write this:

```
const int SECS = 60 * MINUTE; //at namespace level
```

at namespace level, then it is equivalent to this:

```
static const int SECS = 60 * MINUTE;
```

Because **at namespace level** `const` variables has *internal* linkage by default. So the `static` keyword doesn't do anything if `const` is already there — except for increasing the readability.

Now what if you want the variable to have *external* linkage **and** `const` at the same time, well then use `extern`:

```
//.h file 
extern const int SECS;   //declaration

//.cpp file
extern const int SECS = 60 * MINUTE; //definition
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is one of the differences between C99 and C++ -- `const` variables at file scope (namespace scope in C++) have *internal* linkage in C++ and *external* linkage in C99 -- see [here](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm#C99-const-linkage)

Comment: @TristanBrindle: Thanks for sharing that knowledge. I didn't know that. I don't know C/C99 enough. I don't code in C/C99. Fortunately this question is tagged as `C++` only.

Comment: "The order doesn't matter _in this case_" maybe, nevertheless "`const static`" will always seem _wrong_ to me. `static` is a storage-class-specifier, it applies to the _variable_, whereas `const` is a cv-qualifier, it applies to the _type_ (to the left, or immediate right). So to me the correct pattern is "`static` `int const` `SECS`" (or "`static` `const int` `SECS`"). (A maybe better example is `static int const* p` (or `static const int* p`) where `p` is declared static but not const, whereas the pointed-to `int` is declared const but not static.)

Comment: @gx_: `static` is a muti-facted keyword: it defines storage; it defines linkage; it defines membership (with class and instances). But you have a point, nevertheless. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz The point is not that `static` defined as a "storage class specifier" by the grammar (like `extern` btw) or that it has different meanings depending on context (both are true). The point is that it should come first in a declaration, before any type or `const`. (_Edit:_ ok I see you actually agreed.) Btw I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12006039